# Como controlar coordenadas de tela?

Tags: lua

eu preciso desenvolver um programa em Lua (aplicação desktop) que manipule coordenadas de tela, não precisa ser um ambiente gráfico (GUI), mas preciso ser capaz de, por exemplo, posicionar na coordenada (10, 10) - linha 10, coluna 10, e então exibir um texto, e posteriormente voltar a posicionar nessas coordenadas para exibir outro texto. O único jeito é utilizar um toolkit gráfico?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer mover o cursor numa tela de terminal, você pode usar sequencias de escape para terminais, como em [lua-term](https://github.com/hoelzro/lua-term).

O seu exemplo seria:

```
term.cursor.goto(10, 10)
io.write("um texto")
...
term.cursor.goto(10, 10)
io.write("outro texto")
```

Você nem precisa usar uma biblioteca:  `term.cursor.goto(10, 10)` é equivalente a `io.write("\027[10;10H")`. Veja também essa [mensagem](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-12/msg00937.html).

Para uma lista das sequencias de escape mais comuns, veja por exemplo http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php.

Comment: Genial, resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! :)