# Como detectar o mouse, em Lua?

Tags: lua

Recentemente consegui resolver um problema relacionado ao controle de coordenadas de tela em um terminal (graças à resposta encontrada aqui no SOpt). Agora preciso detectar os movimentos e cliques de um dispositivo apontador (mouse).
É hora de pensar e um *toolkit gráfico*, ou existe alguma alternativa mais simples?

Comment: A biblioteca padrão de Lua é super simplezinha, e basicamente só expõe coisas que vem da biblioteca padrão de C. Assim como no caso das coordenadas de terminal, você vai ter que usar alguma biblioteca para mexer com o mouse.

Comment: Obrigado hugomg. Estou experimentando o IUP. Com relação às coordenadas na tela, eu utilizei essa resposta [link] http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23176/como-controlar-coordenadas-de-tela

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Resolvi o meu problema utilizando o IUP (ambiente gráfico)... Mas, de fato, não consegui resolver o problema do mouse em modo terminal. :(

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução para detectar os movimentos do mouse com Lua e em modo terminal seria utilizar o [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/), que costuma já vir integrado em algumas implementações.

Basicamente, você chama:

```
pt = wx.wxGetMousePosition()
io.write(pt.x) -- é a posição em x do ponteiro
io.write(pt.y) -- é a posição em y do ponteiro
```

---

Exemplo

```
require("wx")

-- Loop que vai atualizar o mostrador da posição do mouse:
while true do

    -- wx.wxGetMousePosition() retorna a posição do mouse na tela
    pt = wx.wxGetMousePosition()

    -- atualiza o mostrador:
    io.write("x = " .. pt.x .. "\ny = " .. pt.y .. "\n")
    os.execute("cls") -- ou os.execute("clear") em Unix
end
```